# php not loading and intended prompt not happening

Tags: javascript, php, html

I followed a tutorial to tryout an interface between a server and a webpage. It doesn't work when I place all 3 files html,js,php on my desktop. I understand that php is a server side script thus placed the 3 files on a web host folder public_html. When I run it, it doesn't work either. Can please tell me what I am doing wrong. I believe the codes are right considering it is from a tutorial. Am I placing the files in the wrong place? Thanks for help.

Note: When the html loads and I enter information in the text box, there is supposed to be a prompt below telling me if the entered item exists. In my case, it prompts nothing thus not working.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="foodstore.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="process()">
        <h3>The Chuff Bucket</h3>
        <p>Enter the food you want to enter:</p>
        <input type="text" id="userInput" />
        <div id="underInput" />
    </body>
</html>
```

js

```
var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject(); 

function createXmlHttpRequestObject(){
    var xmlHttp;

    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        //in case user using IE
        try{
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false; 
        }
    }
    //firefox, chrome
    else{
        try{
            xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        }
        catch(e){
            xmlHttp = false; 
        }
    }

    if (!xmlHttp) {
        alert("Can't create object"); 
    }
    else{
        return xmlHttp; 
    }


function process(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==0 || xmlHttp.readyState==4 ) {
        food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
        xmlHttp.open("GET", "foodstore.php?food=" + food, true); 
        xml.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;  
        xmlHttp.send(null); 
    }
    else{
        setTimeOut("process()", 1000);
    }
}

function handleServerResponse(){
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4) {
        if (xmlHttp.status==200) {
            xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML; 
            xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement; 
            message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data; 
            document.getElementById("underInput").innerHTML = '<span style="color:blue">' + message + '</span>'; 
            setTimeOut("process()", 1000);
        }
        else{
            alert("Something went wrong!"); 
        }
    }
}
```

php

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml"); 
    echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>";

    echo "<response>";
        $food = $ GET["food"];
        $foodName = array("tuna", "bacon", "beef", "loaf", "ham";
        if (in_array($food, $foodName) {  
            echo "We do have " . $food. "!";
        }

        elseif (food == "") {
            echo "Please enter the food name.";
        }

        else{
            echo "We do not have " . $food. "!";
        }
    echo "</response>";
?>
```

Comment: you have syntax errors. You have semicolons(`;`) after your if blocks, `if else` blocks do not get semicolons  after them. As such you should be getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token else` or similar error on the console. Also your php array is named `$foodName` not `$foodArray` you should have gotten a error about this in your server logs

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. The syntax error wasn't pointed out as how it normally does for me in visual studio when I code c#. Seems sublime is not the best editor for this work.

Comment: Well semicolons end statements they are just not used to end if else blocks hence why they didnt point it out.

Comment: Hmm have updated the codes and removed the semicolons and renamed the array and it is still not working.

Comment: You cannot have double quotes inside of double quotes without escaping the inner double quotes `"\""` (look at your first `echo`). or use single quotes (`'`) on the inside/outside

Comment: Thanks, yet another syntax mistake. I have corrected it and still not working. I believe I got more syntax errors. I will go loo them up properly instead of asking for debugging favors. :) But can I just double check. Placing all 3 files in the web host public_html will work provided syntax is correct. Placing all 3 files on my desktop will not work even if snytax is correct. Am I right?

Comment: That's correct, @user3439075, unless you have PHP and Apache installed on your desktop.

Comment: Tnks. I get the picture that I use a javascript to call on the php script to access the database. This is fine for the web interface as the js file can be in the same folder as the php file. But for a mobile application, the js would of course not be in the same place. Pondering how a js file would be written in this case. It makes a request to the php file using urls and log in information?